# Is there a way to compute the matrix logarithm of a PyTorch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to compute matrix logarithms in PyTorch but I need to keep tensors because I then apply gradients which means I can't use NumPy arrays.
Basically I'm trying to do the equivalent of [ScyPy's `scipy.linalg.logm()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.logm.html) but with PyTorch tensors.

Comment: have you tried applying `scipy.linalg.logm` on some `torch.tensor`? from my experiments there is some error associated with this, but it is only of order `10^-5`

Comment: @Hadar OP is asking for a version that is compatible with pytorch autograd engine - unfortunately this does not apply to the scipy implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the matrix logarithm (unlike the [matrix exponential](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.matrix_exp.html)) is [not implemented yet](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9983#top), but [matrix powers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.matrix_power.html#torch.linalg.matrix_power) are, this means
in the mean time you can approximate the matrix logarithm by using a the [power series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Power_series_expression), and just truncate it after you get a sufficient accuracy.

Alternatively [Lezcano](https://github.com/Lezcano) proposes a (slow) solution of a differentiable matrix logarithm via adjoint [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9983#issuecomment-891777620). I'll cite their suggested solution:

```py
import scipy.linalg
import torch

def adjoint(A, E, f):
    A_H = A.T.conj().to(E.dtype)
    n = A.size(0)
    M = torch.zeros(2*n, 2*n, dtype=E.dtype, device=E.device)
    M[:n, :n] = A_H
    M[n:, n:] = A_H
    M[:n, n:] = E
    return f(M)[:n, n:].to(A.dtype)

def logm_scipy(A):
    return torch.from_numpy(scipy.linalg.logm(A.cpu(), disp=False)[0]).to(A.device)

class Logm(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, A):
        assert A.ndim == 2 and A.size(0) == A.size(1)  # Square matrix
        assert A.dtype in (torch.float32, torch.float64, torch.complex64, torch.complex128)
        ctx.save_for_backward(A)
        return logm_scipy(A)

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, G):
        A, = ctx.saved_tensors
        return adjoint(A, G, logm_scipy)

logm = Logm.apply
```

Comment: Very interesting, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Easy to implement in PyTorch as follows:

```
import torch

a=torch.randn(5,10)
cov=torch.cov(a)
u, s, v = torch.linalg.svd(cov)
log_cov=torch.matmul(torch.matmul(u, torch.diag_embed(torch.log(s))), v)
```

**You can easily verify that log_cov and log_cov_np are the same.**

```
log_cov_np=scipy.linalg.logm(cov.detach().numpy())
```

if cov is singular, you can use the regularization methods to make it have good condition number for calculating the matrix-log.